# Can you call data from a column in one table to be used in another table in SQL and Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `staff` table that contains the details of staff members and there is another table called `maintenance` where the time they worked needs to be added. I have an empty combo box and I would like to populate that box with the staff from the `staff` table so that when a selection is made and the hours they worked is entered and the submit button is clicked, it will save as a record in the `maintenance` table

here is my combo box code:

```
<div>               
<label>Select technician</label>
<select name="technician" >
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Old"></option>
<option value="New"></option>
</select>
</div>
```

here is my model:

```
class Maintenance extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table='maintentance_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['date'];
    use HasFactory;
}
```

and in my controller, I have this line of code:

```
  $energy->technician= $request->input('technician');
```

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: Put `protected $guarded = [];` in your model. For more info refer to [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to this line of code to your model:

```
protected $guarded = ['id];
```

this will help laravel model to know which column could be updated using eloquent.